# Trying to load +50 images into objects that display them, is there a short way of doing it?

Tags: c#, image, object, factory

to put it short I have a grid system which is made out of tiles, each tile has attributes, one of which is filepath. I want to load 50 different tiles all with different attributes, filepaths etc, for example tile 1 is grass, so filepath is grass.png and isWalkable = true. The way I'm doing it now is

```
    public string[] Names = new string[50];
    public string[] Filepaths = new string[50];
    public bool[] IsWalkable = new bool[50];
    public Color[] BaseColor = new Color[50];
    public Image[] Images = new Image[50];
```

and then

```
        Names[0] = "Grass";
        Filepaths[0] = "img\\grass.png";
        IsWalkable[0] = true;
        BaseColor[0] = Color.Empty;
        Images[0] = new Bitmap("img\\grass.png");
```

then i loop through each tile and give it the the value

```
                Tiles[x, y] = new Tile();
                Tiles[x, y].Name = Names[counter];
                Tiles[x, y].Filepath = Filepaths[counter];
                Tiles[x, y].IsWalkable = IsWalkable[counter];
                Tiles[x, y].BaseColor = BaseColor[counter];
                Tiles[x, y].TerrainImage = Images[counter];
                counter++;
```

I am almost 100% certain that this is a bad way of handling my tile creation, I heard something about maybe having to use a factory, which I looked up but I didn't know how i could incorporate it into my project, so I'm here wondering if anyone has any idea of any method I could use. Please keep it relatively simple or try to explain if it gets complex since I am still new in the fields of programming, thanks!

Comment: It'd be better to use a class `MyClass` that had properties `Name`,`FilePath`,etc.  Then have an object `MyClass[50]`

Comment: Thanks will definitely consider it, still doesn't resolve the issue of hard coding everything though.

Comment: No, that's why it's not an answer :)

Comment: Oh sorry still quite new to the website, apologies. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

define your class:

```
public class ImageInfo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Filepath {get;set;}
    public bool IsWalkable {get;set;}
    public Color BaseColor {get;set;}
    public Image Image {get;set;}
}
```

init your collection (once):

```
var collection = new ImageInfo []
{
    new ImageInfo
    {
        Name = "Grass",
        Filepath = "img\\grass.png",
        IsWalkable = true,
        BaseColor = Color.Empty,
        Image = new Bitmap("img\\grass.png")
    },

    //...
}
```

declare tiles:

```
var tiles = new ImageInfo[10, 10];
```

loop your way:

```
Tiles[x, y] = collection[counter]; counter++;
```

maybe some day you will **load the data from a file or external datasource** (instead of hard-coded it)

Answer (score 0):

You should store that information somewhere, there is no way for the program to know that a grass tile is walkable without you telling it **somewhere**.

Storing that information in a config file (or database or w/e) will make it much more manageable to update instead of doing it all in code.

I'd do something with a `Tile` class

```
public class Tile {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public bool IsWalkable { get; set; }
    public Color BaseColor { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Then set that from your database / config file on load (or as needed)